# How to implement an alert dialog in androidX

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, androidx, material-components-android

I have migrated my project to androidX, and I want to implement an alert dialog with positive and negative feedback from the user.

I am using this code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());

               builder1.setMessage("Write your message here.");
               builder1.setCancelable(true);

               builder1.setPositiveButton(
                       "Yes",
                       new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                               Log.d("MSG", "onClick: YES");
                           }
                       });

               builder1.setNegativeButton(
                       "No",
                       new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                               dialog.cancel();
                               Log.d("MSG", "onClick: No");

                           }
                       });

               AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
               alert11.show();
```

But I get this error when running the app:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md) provided by the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Just use:

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle("Dialog")
            .setMessage("Write your message here. ....")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", /* listener = */ null)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", /* listener = */ null)
            .show();
```

The `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` requires a Material theme and will result in an `androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog`.

Comment: Thank's man i'll give it a shot.